# corrupted stack trace gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

How I can fix this gdb backtrace I seen many answer but I don't found a clear one

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000188c5126 in ___chkstk_ms ()
from C:\msys64\home\IEUser\gimp_master\lib\gegl-0.4\paint-select.dll
#1  0x00000000002000f8 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

the code is [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/-/blob/master/operations/workshop/external/paint-select.cc) on linux it work not on windows

Comment: Your program is broken. Fix the program.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I know the program is broken so I need the gdb bt..

Comment: If the program corrupts its stack, then the stack will be corrupt when gdb tries to look at it. You have to fix the program _without_ depending on `gdb bt`. You can try using valgrind or an address sanitizer to find out where your stack is getting smashed.

Comment: If you cannot use valgrind or address sanitizer, you can rin the program step by step in gdb and observe at which step the stack becomes corrupt. For a long program you need to find the location approximately first, by inserting some checkpoints (debugger breakpoints or prints) at strategic location.

Comment: @Useless thanks this is more clear